# Visual Studio: Shortcut Info

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

for some/most of the functions in Visual Studio there do exist shortcuts. Sadly it's hard to find them.

I'm looking for a addin/tool that will display me information for a shortcut.

For example:

1. I comment a line with `//` and the tools gives me information that the shortcut for this is `STRG + K, C`.
2. I press some button, let's say `debug` and it shows me that the shortcut would be `F5`

Answer (score 1):

For offline use there's the [posters with key bindings](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13189), but inside VS I'd recommend the [IntelliCommand extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/83f59659-abc1-4bfa-9779-42f687af0481) which will show you key combinations when you press `ctrl` (`+ some other key`).

Comment: This is just a list of shortcuts. I like both links, but I'm more looking for some more intelligent addin. Something that really helps learning shortcuts for action I use often.

Answer (score 0):

No other addin/tool required. In Visual Studio, under `Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard`, you can find all available shortcuts.
[image]